# Compiling less and inserting CSS into a template with webpack

Tags: javascript, build, webpack

Is it possible for webpack to compile a series of `.less` partials, and insert them into a html template as CSS?

I have a component that looks like this

```
/banner
 - template.html
 - index.js
 - style.less
```

`style.less` looks like

```
@import "../style/index.less"
.banner {
  background-color: red;
}
```

`template.html` looks like

```
<div class="banner">
    This is a banner
</div>
```

Just wondering if theres any way of getting the output to look like...

```
<style>
/* 
    Imported index.less style
*/
.banner {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
<div class="banner">
    This is a banner
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use extract-text-plugin to extract css to other file:

```
  {
    test: /\.less$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
      loader: ["css-loader", "less-loader"],
    })
  },
```

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/250